# EGit fails with "git-upload-pack: command not found"

Tags: git, eclipse

I know very little about git or [EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/).  I installed EGit into [Eclipse Indigo](http://eclipse.org/).  I got a git path from someone who has some code in that repo.  I tried to clone the repo.  It failed with the following (name, host, and path elided):

```
Cannot list the available branches.
Reason:
myname@myhost:mypath: cannot execute:
git-upload-pack 'mypath'
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
```

I then logged onto the box with Putty, using the same credentials and ran "which git-upload-pack", and it returned "/usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack".

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR – try to add the following to `~/.bashrc` on your remote machine:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/local/bin"
```

---

The issue probably is that the `$PATH` for your PuTTy connection and the Git connection is different.

So whenever you login over PuTTy, `~/.bash_profile` is executed and sets your path correctly, whereas with Git, `~/.bashrc` is executed and fails to set the path to your Git binary. Take a look at both `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`, and `~/.bashrc` for any statements like `export PATH`. My guess is that in the former one, the path to `/usr/local/bin` is set, whereas it is not in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I figured it out.  It was executing my .bashrc directly, and I had put the /usr/local/bin path into my local.profile.  Once I added /usr/local/bin to my .bashrc, it started working.